# RTK query - query not initiated

Tags: rtk-query

I am a beginner attempting to learn RTK query from the [documentation](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-7-rtk-query-basics).

I've created a stripped down version to simplify the learning process but, despite copying the key code directly from the docs, there doesn't appear to be any api call; redux dev tools only shows an an @@INIT state and the queries object in the tree is empty.

[Screen shot of redux dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uta9O.png)

This is the **RTK query**:

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

export const apiSlice = createApi({
  reducerPath: "apiSlice",

  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com",
  }),

  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getComments: builder.query({
      query: () => "/posts/1/comments",
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useGetCommentsQuery } = apiSlice;
```

**The Store**

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { apiSlice } from "../utils/api/apiSlice";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    [apiSlice.reducerPath]: apiSlice.reducer,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(apiSlice.middleware),
});
```

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from "./App";

import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "./store/store";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Finally, **Comments.js** (which is initiated within )

```
import React from "react";
import { useGetCommentsQuery } from "../../utils/api/apiSlice";

export const Comments = () => {
  const { data: comments = [] } = useGetCommentsQuery;
  console.log(comments);

  const content = comments.map((comment) => (
    <li key={comment.id}>{comment.name}</li>
  ));

  return (
    <section>
      <h1>test</h1>
      <div>{content}</div>
    </section>
  );
};
```

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: You need to call the hook, so you need parentheses. `const { data: comments = [] } =  useGetCommentsQuery()`

Comment: @LindaPaiste - thank you very much!